# Swift initialization when you don't know what value to initialize with

Tags: swift

I am learning swift and am quite surprised at a paradigm, I would like to better understand, about initialization. (please note I am not a professional developer).

In the following code, I get an error at build time on the last line :

*Variable 'ex1' used before being initialized*

```
class Example {
var data:Int
init (value: Int){
    self.data = value
}
}
var ex1: Example
var ex2: Example

for i in 1...2 {
    switch i {
    case 1:
        ex1 = Example(value: 10)
    case 2 :
        ex2 = Example(value: 20)
    default:
        break
    }
}

var result = ex1
```

So, my understanding is that the compiler is not smart enough to understand that ex1 is initialized at execution in the "for" loop before.

Ok fine. So now I have to initialize my variables a priori, to a random value. This seems odd to me, as not initializing them feels as a safety to spot errors.

Now I have to carry a possibly wrong value without warning. Is this the good practice ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: The compiler knows that there are cases in your switch where `ex1` is never initialized — like `default`.

Comment: Besides, in general the practice of declaring a variable without initializing it right then and there in the same line is a bad practice. It's unclear what your purpose is, other than to yank the compiler's chain unnecessarily and unrealistically.

Comment: Basically, the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out what you're doing. Don't write needlessly complex code and situations like this should almost never happen (for the rare exceptions, that's what implicitly unwrapped optionals are for).

Comment: My problem is, I don't see the point of initializing a variable I don't know the value of yet, at the moment I declare it.

Comment: @Hugues There are cases where you can do that, and where the compiler will be satisfied, but the example in your question isn't a good one. I'll try to show a better one.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery To clarify, this is a very simplified version of a problem I met in a more complex code, where I initialized the value of the variables in a loop, and could not use them outside of the loop. Seems really strange to me. What the purpose of initializing variables with values you know to be wrong ?

Comment: @matt (1) you can replicate the problem without a switch. Just use a "if then else"

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to declare a variable without initializing it immediately and without the compiler complaining. For example:

```
let ex: Example
if someBoolean {
    ex = Example(value: 10)
} else {
    ex = Example(value: 20)
}
print(ex) // this should work fine
```

However, the compiler only knows how to handle this if all declared variables are initialized in *all logical paths*. In your question, you only initialize one variable in each case of the switch, and neither in the default. You may know that they will all be initialized by the end of the loop, but the compiler isn't smart enough to figure that out.

There's also very few situations where you would want to do that anyway. If you find yourself needing to initialize different variables in different stages of a loop, there's a good chance you're doing something wrong or you could write your code more efficiently. It's hard to say how to simplify your actual code without seeing it, but for the example code you would get the same result by simply immediately initializing both variables.

If you **must** do it that way, and you **know** all of the variables will be initialized before they're used but the compiler doesn't, you can use implicitly unwrapped optionals:

```
var ex1: Example!
var ex2: Example!
// other code is the same
```

As with all uses of force/implicit unwrapping, this comes with the risk of your app crashing if you made a mistake or forgot an edge case, so I only recommend it if there aren't any other ways of doing it, or if the other ways require excessively complex code.

Comment: Example! is what I was looking after.

My problem was I was using a loop to process several keyboard inputs and assign different variables at each loop occurence, depending on the loop occurence.

I still find hard to cope with the fact that I have to initialize a variable at declaration (with a bogus value) as a good practice. The purpose of a variable is to change, sometimes it is tiresome to do if it is a class variable itself having class properties. And I don’t see the benefit. 
I guess I’m missing something there.

Comment: @Hugues Variables can change, yes, but you still have to give them a value before you can use them, and the compiler tries to enforce that. It just isn't always right in complex cases. That's where the implicitly unwrapped optional comes in, you're basically telling the compiler that you know better and it's definitely going to have a value before you use it.